# Python "if" statements

Tags: python

trying to make it answer the question but python denys it

```
questionTwo == int(input("2. What year will the next Stanley Cup occur? "))
if questionTwo == '2014':
    print("Correct")
else:
    print("Not Correct")
```

Comment: if you're going to `int` it, then it will never equal a string

Comment: You are explicitly saying `int()` and do  then a comparison with a `'string'`.

Answer (score 4):

You are comparing an `int` and a `str`, which is why your program isn't working. Try:

```
if questionTwo == 2014:
    print("Correct")
else:
    print("Not Correct")
```

Comment: Fair point. My assumption was that the OP will want to use `questionTwo` some time later in his/her code.

Comment: A totally reasonable assumption.

Answer (score 4):

The first line should say `questionTwo = int(input("2. What year will the next Stanley Cup occur? "))`. Your use of `==` doesn't assign to `questionTwo`, it computes whether `questionTwo` is equal to the int. You don't post your error, but the error is probably that `questionTwo` is not defined.

Comment: but then when i do that i type the correct answer and it still says not correct

Comment: That's what you do. You fix a problem, and then you fix the next problem. You keep going until it works.

Comment: @user2929365 You need to combine the top two answers here.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to compare integers with strings, that will never succeed.

Answer (score 0):

You are taking `questionTwo` as `int` and in `if` statement checking `questionTwo` as a string.

change `if questionTwo == '2014':` to `if questionTwo == 2014:`